# How to start WildFly as a service with standalone-full.xml?

Tags: windows, service, wildfly-8

WildFly provides a `service.bat` in `%WILDFLY_HOME%\bin\service`. Calling the batch file with the `install` parameter installs WildFly as a service on Windows.

I have made changes to the `standalone.conf` and need to use the `standalone-full.xml` in my setup. Hence, I would like to start the WildFly service with these parameters on Windows. Is it possible? How do I do it?

Comment: Just to mention that starting from 10th it is located in `\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\docs\contrib\scripts\service`

Answer (score 13):

Yes, It is possible. You should only change SERVER_OPTS variable on **standalone.bat** file. In addition, you do not have to make changes on **standalone.conf**.

Put below line and try again.

```
set "SERVER_OPTS=--server-config=standalone-full.xml"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just create the service with the command `service.bat install /config standalone-full.xml`

Comment: In WildFly 10 this option is no longer available: `ERROR: Unrecognised option: /config`

Comment: It is. I used the above while upgrading from Wildfly 8 to 10. Just now I checked service.bat and the /config command is still in there. There must be another problem.

Comment: Solved: my WildFly 10.1 download was corrupt, it works now with NetBeans 10.1. Many thanks for the hint!

Comment: Not available in WildFly 8.2.1

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Windows machine and have set Environment variable for Wildfly, goto command prompt and type the following command.

```
standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml
```

This should start wildfly in the standalone-full configuration.

Answer (score 1):

When running WildFly standalone server as a Windows service, `service install` registers start command `standalone.bat` with no option.

By default, `standalone.bat` loads `standalone.conf.bat`, and not `standalone.conf` which is designed to Unix platforms.

It is possible to load a specific `standalone.conf.bat` file setting environment variable `STANDALONE_CONF` with its path. There, it is possible to set `JAVA_OPTS` options but not server options.

To avoid to edit WildFly release `standalone.bat` file, I recommend to create a copy of `bin/service/service.bat` as `bin/service/service-myproject.bat` where you can adapt start parameters and add `--server-config`:

```
set STARTPARAM="/c \"set NOPAUSE=Y ^^^&^^^&
    standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml\""
```

At the same time, this specific `service-myproject.bat` allows you to tune your service installation with `SHORTNAME`, `DISPLAYNAME` and `DESCRIPTION` variables.

Do not forget to invoke `service-myproject.bat` with both `/user` and `/password` options so that the service is allowed to cleanly stop your instance with granted administrative user.